# Evaluate $ \int^4_1 e^ \sqrt {x}dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $ \int^4_1 e^ \sqrt {x}dx $
>
> **solution**:-
>
> Here $1<x<4$
>
> $1<\sqrt x<2$
>
> $e<e^ \sqrt {x}<e^ 2$
>
> $\int^4_1 $e dx$<\int^4_1 e^ \sqrt {x}dx<\int^4_1 e^ 2dx$
>
> $3e  <\int^4_1 e^ \sqrt {x}dx<3 e^ 2 $

But in this objective question

Options are

a)$e $

b)$e^2 $

c)$2e $

d)$2e^2 $

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Make the substitution $x=t^2$ to get the integral $2\int_1^2 te^t \mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: thanks a lot . your method is better than mine

Answer (score 2):

HINT: 
$$
3 e < 2e^2 < 3e^2
$$
As suggested, the substitution $x=t^2$ yields
$$
2\int_1^2 te^t dt 
$$
Using integration by parts, you get 
$$
2\int_1^2 te^t dt = 2\left([te^t]_1^2 - \int_1^2 e^t dt\right) = 2 \left( 2e^2 - e^1 -e^2 + e^1 \right) = 2 e^2
$$

Comment: So you mean ans is (d)$2e^2$

Comment: Yes. Do you know how to calculate?

Comment: I think $2e^2 > 3e$ so  $3e^2>2e^2 > 3e$

Comment: That is the same as in my answer but reversed :)

Comment: Thanks. But I have to choose only one ans